# inconsistant return value of console.timeEnd()

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have following snippet taken from [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_time_label),

```
console.time('100-elements');
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { }
console.timeEnd('100-elements');
// prints 100-elements: 225.438ms
```

When I run the above snippet locally **in VS-Code** (in node environment), the console logs twice, this is basically looged by `console.timeEnd()` something like,

```
100-elements: 0.009033203125ms
100-elements: 0.285ms
```

Also, when I do `console.time('foo')` nothing is logged, unless I do `console.timeEnd('foo')` which in turn logs two times.

**What can be the reason for this behaviour?**

Looking into [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_time_label) docs and [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) also I didn't find any mention of `console.time()` logging any time. More importantly,

**What does the time returned by `console.timeEnd()` indicate ?**

**UPDATE:** When I run the script from the terminal (macOS's default terminal) it prints output as expected; however the above behaviour was observed when debugging using VS-Code.

Also, to make myself more clear, the dual logs are printed via `console.timeEnd()`

Node version is: v10.16.

here's my `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "foo",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "*What does the time returned by console.time() indicate ?*" `console.time` just *starts* a timer with a given name. `console.timeEnd` stops the timer and prints how long it took from starting it.

Comment: With node v10.16.0, I only get one printout. What version of node are you using?

Comment: the call to `console.time` returns `undefined` and does **not** log any time for me (node 12.10.0)

Comment: @jfriend00: That piece of information is already provided in the question.

Comment: The nodejs code for `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_time_label).  Have a look and see what it does.  When I run it in node v10.16, I don't get any logging from `console.time('someLabel')`, only from `console.timeEnd('someLabel')`.

Comment: guys, this works perfectly as expected when I ran the script via macOS's default terminal